# How to save nested array in MongoDB using Mongoose and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

Can anyone explain me how to save the nested array items into mongodb with mongoose and nodejs?.

Here is a schema I am using.

```
var demoSchema = ({
    "r_id": Number,
    "r_label": String,
    "entity": [{
        "d_label": String,
        "d_type": String
      }
    ]
})
```

And here is Nodejs function I am using to save the data into db

```
 app.route("/mypages/rooms")
  .post(function(req, res) {
   var db = mongoOp.demo();
   var response = {};
   req.checkBody("r_id", "Enter a valid r_id address.").notEmpty();
   req.checkBody("r_label", "Enter a valid label address.").notEmpty();

   var errors = req.validationErrors();
   if (errors) {
     console.log(errors);
     console.log(req.body);
     res.status(500);
     res.end('500 Server Error');
     //res.render('addrooms',{flag:1});
     return;
     } else {
         db.r_id = req.body.r_id;
         db.r_label = req.body.r_label;
         db.entity = req.body.entity;
         db.save(function(err) {
          if (err) {
           findfromdb(req, res, 2); //own function for implementation purpose
          } else {
           findfromdb(req, res, 1);
          }
        });
        //var middleVar = req.body.resources;
      //  console.log(middleVar[0].d_rgb);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set entity with array `[]`

`db.entity = [{}];`

```
app.route("/mypages/rooms")
  .post(function(req, res) {
   var db = mongoOp.demo();
   var response = {};
   req.checkBody("r_id", "Enter a valid r_id address.").notEmpty();
   req.checkBody("r_label", "Enter a valid label address.").notEmpty();

   var errors = req.validationErrors();
   if (errors) {
     console.log(errors);
     console.log(req.body);
     res.status(500);
     res.end('500 Server Error');
     //res.render('addrooms',{flag:1});
     return;
     } else {
         db.r_id = req.body.r_id;
         db.r_label = req.body.r_label;
         db.entity = [{
                      "d_label": req.body.label_type,
                      "d_type": req.body.d_type
                     }];
         db.save(function(err) {
          if (err) {
           findfromdb(req, res, 2); //own function for implementation purpose
          } else {
           findfromdb(req, res, 1);
          }
        });
        //var middleVar = req.body.resources;
      //  console.log(middleVar[0].d_rgb);
     }
 });
```

---

The below operation adds the element `label_type` and `d_type` to entity array if they does not exist in the array, if they exists, then they won't be added

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

```
Model.update(
    query, //  { _id: 1 }
    {
        $addToSet: {
            "enity": {
                "d_label": req.body.label_type,
                "d_type": req.body.d_type
            }
        }
    }
)
```

have a look at this answer

[Pushing item to Mongodb collection array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350282/pushing-item-to-mongodb-collection-array/42350582#42350582)

Comment: Can you help to find out way to update the same schema?. Let's say I already have one d_label and d_type and I need to update with one more entry.

Comment: yes, you have to use `$addToset`, Shall i update mine answer and add another method for `$addToset`

Comment: Yes, It will be useful

Comment: will you be adding new object to the entity or only perform update,, I mean will add more entity {}  with d_label and d_type in array

Comment: I will add more entity only.